# Git checkout to sub-directory in Jenkins fails job

Tags: git, go, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Working on CI for our Golang project.

After I installed Jenkins on Windows master, I configured first Freestyle project.
For the sake of building golang project, the project code must be in the GOPATH under `src`. This is in my case inside `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\go\`.

I made some modifications to Git Repository options inside `Source code management` in Jenkins. I set `Check out to sub-directory`  to `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\go\src\nhm` so the go project would et pulled inside GOPATH. After I did that, the `git-fetch` step starts to fail.

The error is:

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
stderr: error: cannot spawn C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\go\src\nhm@tmp\ssh3120648910683130753.bat: No such file or directory
```

Jenkins directories weren't changed (this includes workspaceDir `${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}` and buildsDir `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds` )

What am I missing here? When gets this .bat file generated so it can be used afterwards for the sake of git-clone?

Comment: I think the Jenkins  does not have administartive rights, so it is not allowed to create the temp files.

Comment: @S.Spieker is there any way to give Jenkins rights instead of modifying `systemprofile\go\src` directory with permissions?

Comment: System and all users have all permissions for the `systemprofile\go\src`, so this shouldn't be the problem unless there is some special restriction for Jenkins about which I don't know.